# jQtouch with jQuery not Zepto

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

I'm not sure why but I followed instructions below to use jQuery instead of Zepto but it comes with jQTouch object not found error.

```
<script src="../../src/lib/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="../../src/jqtouch.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <!-- Uncomment the following two lines (and comment out the previous two) to use jQuery instead of Zepto. -->
        <!-- <script src="../../src/lib/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="../../src/jqtouch-jquery.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
```

It seems like developer asked to uncomment below and comment above if I wanted to use jQuery but it doesn't seem to work at all?

Anyone got jQuery working with this?

The reason is I need to use jQuery UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it with a little trial and error. It turns out that the instruction "Uncomment the following two lines (and comment out the previous two) to use jQuery instead of Zepto" is inaccurate.

Instead, of commenting out the previous two, just comment out the zepto.min.js line and leave the jqtouch.min.js line as-is. It seems to be working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

also the question isn't very clear (what framework? what are you trying to do, what developer ? etc) I would guess the answer is commenting the uncomment line, uncommenting the commented line and **making sure that you actually have jquery and jqtouch in the specific folder**.  also you should change the type to "text/javascript".

again don't know if that is the problem, since you don't show us what is it you are trying to use.